# Create dynamic tree view grid with multiple columns in angular 6

Tags: angular, treeview

I need to create a dynamic tree grid view structure with multiple columns with N level

### Id Column, Name Column,                Type Column

1. parent1

   - child.

     - child1

       - child 1.1

         - child 1.1.1
         - child 1.1.2
     - child2
   - Four spaces again.
2. parent2

   - child.

     - child1

       - child 1.1

         - child1.1.2
     - child2

Answer (score 0):

you can acheive this multilevel treeview using ngx-treeview.
For that your data to be structured similar to the tree.
you can check the exmaple here :
https://leovo2708.github.io/ngx-treeview/#/components

Comment: I need to construct the tree structure dynamically. When i click on parent child node details should get populated